# Solving Uni-variate Circular and Sine wave regression by Minimum Mean Square Error MMSE method

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, regression, computational-mathematics, gradient-descent

I need help understanding and finding MMSE for these two, I researched on my own but i found many solutions that dealt with matrices(from what I understand those dealt with multiple variables) I don't want those answers I want to get some answers using this approach:

Number1:
$$   y= \sin(wx)$$
Number2:
$$   x^2+y^2=r^2$$

[For understanding problem see these two pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCyjb.png)

Here consider that both x and y are known we are to minimize the remaining variable in these questions.

What I did regarding Number1:

For $x^2+y^2=r^2$ , I made the loss function as the sum of differences of distance between the true fit(the one that has least error) and a random fit, using distance formula for a point and circle.

$$ Loss=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(d_{j} -(\sqrt{x^2_{j}+y^2_{j}}-r))^2 $$
By solving using MMSE for r i got:
$$r=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(d_{j}-\sqrt{x^2_{j}+y^2_{j}})$$
**Question-1:** Is the approach and the answer correct?

What I did regarding Number2:

For $y= \sin(wx)$ , I made the loss function as the sum of difference between two sine curves one best(minimized) other random.

$$Loss=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(y_{j}-sin(w*x_{j}))^2$$
By solving using MMSE for w I got:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(y_{j}-sin(w*x_{j}))*(cos(w*x_{j})*x_{j})=0$$

Another approach that might be right is to find the distance between data points and the sine curve.If the points on the sine curve are of the form (x,sin(wx)). The distance of a point (e,f) to the points on sine curve is:

$$D = \sqrt{(x - e)^2 + (\sin (wx) - f)^2}$$
And then minimize Loss function for $$D^2$$ as the minimization will be same for both.

$$ Loss=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(D^2_{j}-((x_{j} - e)^2 + (\sin (wx_{j}) - f)^2))^2 $$

**Question-2:** Which approach is correct here and in both cases i am unable to seperate $$w$$ what am I doing wrong?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Your approach 1 is correct.But it isn't the usual problem in circular regression. One have not only to find the radius $r$ but also the coordinates $(a,b)$ of the center of the circle. This means that the equation to be fitted is : $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$. For example, see pp.11-13 in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique . I added a numerical example in the answer section because this page cannot be edited here. For the approach 2 probably I misunderstood your question. That is why I delete my previous comment.

Comment: About your approach 2 : This is a problem of sinusoidal regression ( Now, I suppose that it is not related to the first problem of circular regression). The equation to be fitted is $y=\sin(wx)$. Your approach is correct but cannot be solved without an itterrative process in your two cases. This requires somme software for non-linear regression calculus. In case of so simple equation $y=\sin(wx)$ better consider $wx=\sin^{-1}(y)$ which leads to simple linear regression. Note that the usual problem of four parameters sinusoidal regression is to fit the equation $$y=a+b\sin(wx+\phi)$$

Comment: You are right , I edited my question to make it more clear.
If I understood  right there is no unique solution possible for y=sin(wx) as sine is nonlinear function, so we will approach this problem using gradient descent (or some other iterative method ) as we were minimizing the mean squares.Unless we consider $$wx=sin^{-1}(y)$$

Comment: Just to be sure:

For $$wx=sin^{-1}(y)$$
let $$Y=sin^{-1}(y)$$
$$Loss=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(Y_{j}-(wx_{j}))^2
$$

Comment: This is correct. Note that, in practical application, one have to take account that arcsin is multivalued : $Y_j=\sin^{−1}(y_j)+2k_jπ$ or $Y_j=\pi-\sin^{-1}(y_j)+2k'_j\pi$ with integers $k_j$ or $k'_j$ . The correct determination of $k_j$ or $k'_j$ has to be found  for each point. For example see pp.21-36 in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . The sinusoidal regression is a very difficult case of regression. This is not a convenient problem for beginner. Better study polynomial regression for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my above comment, a numerical example of circular regression :

[image]